# PHP htmlentities() on input vs on output

Tags: php, html, xss, sanitization, html-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP htmlentities() on input before DB insert, instead of on output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023728/php-htmlentities-on-input-before-db-insert-instead-of-on-output)

For a PHP application that's simply trying to protect itself against the likes of XSS, at what stage should the `htmlentities()` function be called? Should it be called on the initial user input, or on every page render where that data is outputted?

If I use `htmlentities()` on user input, I end up storing slightly more data in the database. However, in the long run, I save on CPU cycles because I only have to perform the conversion on input, and never again on subsequent output of that data.

I should note that I can't see any foreseeable case of ever having to store HTML input data in my application, so using `htmlentities()` is purely for XSS protection. In the unlikely event that I do ever need the raw HTML, I can simply call `html_entity_decode()` to reverse `htmlentities()`. Additionally, it saves me from forgetting to call `htmlentities()` on page render and accidentally inserting an XSS exploit into my application.

I've toyed with the idea of using Facebook's XHP extension, but the XML parsing induces quite a lot of overhead, more than what I'm comfortable with for my application.

**Summary:** Should I use `htmlentities()` on input or on output? What is the general, accepted approach to this situation?

Comment: Do you consider HTML entities as a *part* of your data?

Comment: Related/Duplicates: [PHP & mySQL: When exactly to use htmlentities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077576/php-mysql-when-exactly-to-use-htmlentities), [PHP htmlentities() on input before DB insert, instead of on output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023728/php-htmlentities-on-input-before-db-insert-instead-of-on-output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you can guarantee that for the lifetime of your application the input is *only* going to be fed to a web browser the matter is not up for discussion: you should use XSS protection on output because otherwise you will end up having to massage your data on output (whatever kind of output that may be) on a case-by-case basis. Which is exactly your current argument for applying the protection on input.

Seeing as it's quite unlikely that the above is true even right now (let alone in an unspecified future time) IMHO the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

i prefer using it at output, that keep the posibility open to use the same data for none html version of outputs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reasons to do it on input.

If you want high performance, just make 2 fields: text, escaped_text and fill 2nd field on 1st output and reset it on update.

If you will use template engine, it will escape all data for you.